# Children selector not working with append

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't this append 'buzz' to my bars?

```
for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
    $('.foo > div').eq(i).children('bar').append('buzz');
}
```

My document structure:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: turns out it was a typo honey bunny.

Comment: I don't know who you're talking to or if you're saying you don't need a solution anymore. In addition to the missing dot before 'bar', there are other problems. Make sure you clarify what the solution was or if it was from a user, accept their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `selector` should be:

```
$('.foo .bar:eq('+i+')').append( HTML to append )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a type error, but checking your html, you need to search for children('.bar'):

```
var jqdivs = $('.foo');
for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 

  jqdivs.eq(i).children('.bar').append('buzz');

}
```

And, in case your html example is not an oversimplification, you should do:

```
$('.foo').children('.bar').append('buzz');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    $('.foo > div').eq(i).append('buzz');
```

Or if you want to make sure only divs of class `bar` are updated:

```
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    $('.foo > div.bar').eq(i).append('buzz');
```

Or, if you're not committed to the for loop:

`$('.foo > div').append('buzz');`

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is work well for what you want :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $foo = $(".foo");
    $foo.find(".bar").each(function(i){
        $(this).append('buzz');
    });
});
```